# 'System.Nullable<bool>' does not contain a definition for 'OK'

Tags: c#, wpf, file, dialog

I'm trying a basic file dialog example from, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.aspx), and I get an error on 'OK', and I don't know why.

> Error 1   'System.Nullable' does not contain a definition for 'OK' and no extension method 'OK' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Stream myStream = null;
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\" ;
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*" ;
    openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2 ;
    openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true ;

    if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        try
        {
            if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
            {
                using (myStream)
                {
                    // Insert code to read the stream here.
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What assembly is your OpenFileDialog from?

Comment: this works, can you be a bit more specific? The error is probably not here...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are two versions of `OpenFileDialog` in the .NET framework: the [WinForms one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog) and the [WPF one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.openfiledialog). It looks like you're using the WPF one, which does, in fact, return a `Nullable<bool>` value from `OpenFile`. The WinForm version returns a `DialogResult` value, which seems to be what you're expecting.

Comment: The version you have linked to is the WIN32 one. I don't think there is one specific to WPF.

Comment: @pug Note that the class in question is defined in the PresentationFramework assembly, one of the core assemblies of WPF.

Answer (score 14):

It sounds like you have a local property called `DialogResult`. Try using `System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK` instead.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like its trying to use [ShowDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.openfiledialog.showdialog(VS.95).aspx) for `System.Windows.Controls`.
Try making the call explicit to `System.Windows.Forms`

Like:

```
System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
```